# Biased latitude and longitude

Tags: gps, geography

I have some geographical data that contains latitude and longitude and also contains columns called biased latitude and longitude. I'm unfamiliar with this term and can't find much info on the internet except for this patent reference: http://www.google.com/patents/US4442491 which I'm not sure is relevant to me.

Does anyone have an explanation for these terms as it applies to geographical coordinates?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about geography rather than programming.  gis.stackexchange.com might be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thank you. I saw a lot of questions tagged with geography and made a wrong assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term Bias means (constant-?) offset and often is used in electrotechnic.
There is no special meaning in geography. 
Just somebody named it so. 
you have to ask the author of that data what is meant.

It could be an offset distance to the original lat, lon.
If you want to reverse engineer, calculate the distance between each lat,lon and the coresponding biased lat lon, using this
code 
[Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points? (Haversine formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula)